# If anyone has experience about bugs ,problems or any related link of DB2 v.10 FOR ZOS , please reply?

Tags: db2, zos

Hi
I want to use db2 10 for zos.
If anyone has experience about bugs ,problems or any related link of DB2 v.10, please reply?

thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running z/OS, you will, or *should*, have a contract with IBM. In that case, you will have access to PMR/APAR information that IBM publish.

You just do a search on the product COMPID(s) to discover any issues and fixes.

If you *don't* have such an agreement with IBM (though, seriously, why would you spend all that money of the OS and products and *not* get support?) , head on over to the [DB2/z product page](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/zos/) and look at the "Product Support" link. The page that brings up has information on all the recent and important PTFs that you should examine.

The COMPIDs from the DB2/z v10 Program Directory are:

```
FMID     COMPID     Component Name
-------  ---------  ----------------------------
HDBAA10  5740XYR00  DB2 BASE/TSO
HIYAA10  5740IY100  IMS ATTACH
HIZAA10  5740XYR01  DB2 SUBSYSTEM INITIALIZATION
HIR2230  569516401  IRLM V02.03.00
HDREA10  5740DRE00  RACF AUTHORIZATION EXIT
JDBAA12  5740XYR02  DB2 JDBC/SQLJ
JDBAA14  5740XYR00  DB2 ENGLISH PANELS
JDBAA17  5740XYR02  DB2 ODBC
JDBAA11  5740XYR06  DB2 KANJI PANELS
```